# Build ROS2 workspace in docker container -- cannot find ament_cmake

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ros2

I have a ROS2 workspace project like this:

```
├── build-in-docker
├── docker
│   ├── build
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── env
└── src
```

`docker/env` has environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOC='\033[0m'
GRN='\033[0;32m'
YLW='\033[0;33m'

image_name="docker-build-ros2"
container_name="ros2-ws"
target_path="/ros2-ws"
```

and `docker/Dockerfile` has content:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

# prepare the docker   -----------------
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# By default, ubuntu docker images include code to remove downloaded packages.
# Use the invocation from examples to avoid this and make the apt cache effective.
RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' \
    > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/keep-cache

ENV ROS_PYTHON_VERSION 3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

# run export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 to enable BuildKit
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y \
    autoconf bash-completion build-essential cmake curl \
    dirmngr gcc git gnupg2 g++ libtool lsb-release \
    pkg-config python3-pip libccd-dev \
    libflann-dev libpcl-dev libyaml-cpp-dev \
    && pip3 install cython \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y \
    ros-foxy-desktop \
    python3-argcomplete \
    python3-colcon-common-extensions \
    python3-colcon-mixin \
    python3-rosdep \
    python3-vcstool \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN rosdep init || true \
    && rosdep update

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo "source /opt/ros/foxy/local_setup.bash" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then, I am going to use `build-in-docker` script to build the ROS2 workspace, the `build-in-docker` has content:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu -o pipefail

script_dir="$(dirname "$0")"
pushd "$script_dir" &>/dev/null

source "$script_dir/docker/env"

# stop the container if it is running ------------------------
if [[ $(docker ps --filter "name=^/${container_name}$" --format '{{.Names}}') == "${container_name}" &&
"$(docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' ${container_name})" == "true" ]]; then
    echo -e "${YLW}Stop container \"${container_name}\"${NOC} ..."
    docker stop ${container_name}
fi

# remove the container if it exists but not running ------------------------
if [[ $(docker ps --filter "name=^/${container_name}$" --format '{{.Names}}') == "${container_name}" ]]; then
    echo -e "${YLW}Remove container \"${container_name}\"${NOC} ..."
    docker rm ${container_name} &>/dev/null
fi

# build an image from Dockerfile ------------------------
echo -e "${GRN}Build the image \"${image_name}\"${NOC} ..."
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
    -t ${image_name} \
    -f docker/Dockerfile docker

# create a container and run it ------------------------
echo -e "${GRN}Run container \"${container_name}\" from image \"${image_name}\"${NOC} ..."
docker run -d -it --rm \
    --name ${container_name} \
    --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=${target_path} \
    ${image_name}

# build the project in the container ------------------------
# ${target_path} ${build_dir}: arguments passed into ./docker/build
echo -e "${GRN}Build the project${NOC} ..."
docker exec ${container_name} ${target_path}/docker/build \
    ${target_path}

# finish
echo -e "${GRN}Project is build successfully.${NOC}"
popd &>/dev/null
```

which calls `docker/build` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu -o pipefail

# project root directory, passed from ../build-in-docker
cd "$1"

/bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash"

colcon build
```

However, it gives me error:

```
Stop container "ros2-ws" ...
ros2-ws
Build the image "docker-build-ros2" ...
[+] Building 0.7s (18/18) FINISHED                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                   0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental             0.1s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:600e5c  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                   0.1s
 => [stage-0  1/12] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:626ffe58f6e7566e0  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  2/12] RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean     && ech  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  3/12] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales       0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  4/12] RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8                             0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  5/12] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  6/12] RUN export LANG=en_US.UTF-8                            0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  7/12] RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/ros  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  8/12] RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architectur  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0  9/12] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 10/12] RUN rosdep init || true     && rosdep update           0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 11/12] RUN echo "source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash" >> /etc/ba  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 12/12] RUN echo "source /opt/ros/foxy/local_setup.bash" >> /  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                            0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                           0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:9af6dcfcf4fa94cec435a91fd48218c6b83c730aada6de85cc86  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker-build-ros2                              0.0s
Run container "ros2-ws" from image "docker-build-ros2" ...
ff1545051e411035142315215ab385d74627d7de65e79a22ec12b0c59f656790
Build the project ...
Starting >>> agv_interfaces
--- stderr: agv_interfaces
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findament_cmake.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "ament_cmake", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake" with
  any of the following names:

    ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
    ament_cmake-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ament_cmake_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ament_cmake" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< agv_interfaces [0.07s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.26s]
  1 package failed: agv_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: agv_interfaces
  1 package not processed
```

However, if I manually enter the container using `docker attach` command, and manually enter the directory and then build the workspace using `colcon build`, the build is successful. After this, if I run again `./build-in-docker` natively, the worspace can be built successfully.

My question is, what setting have I made wrong that I cannot build the workspace from first running `./build-in-docker` command?

Comment: It is a bash related issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42362580/3188768 seems a good answer, however, it does not tell much detail on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in another answer you need to use `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` instead. The new error this produces is because of the line `set -eu -o pipefail` in your `build-in-docker` file. The `-u` flag will treat every unset variable as an error. You can either remove the flag or set `AMENT_TRACE_SETUP_FILES` to some value.

Comment: This solves my problem. `AMENT_TRACE_SETUP_FILES` is not pre-set in the environement, hence `set -eu -o pipefail` will let the script exit.

Answer (score 0):

In your buildscript you're executing:

```
/bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash"
```

Putting `/bin/bash` in front of your command just opens a new commandline, executes the command, and then closes the commandline.
So whatever you source in that command, it will disappear immediately.

Therefore, just change it to:

```
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

Comment: I tried it. it gives me a different error: /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash: line 8: AMENT_TRACE_SETUP_FILES: unbound variable.
I understand the part you say it "opens a new commandline", that is the key problem I need to solve here.

Comment: This sounds like a ROS install issue, try uninstalling ROS Foxy (desktop/ros-base, don't know which you installed), then autoremove all packages, then reinstall. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: it is not ROS issue, because I can build the workspace by manually enter (attach) into the container, and then `source` and then `colcon build`.